# How do I get just the value of the field name?

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I'm trying to use sqlcmd utility and the query is working I'm just wondering how I can get just the value without fieldname and those dashes?

```
$res = sqlcmd -Q @"
    :Connect . 
    use [Database1]

    select firstname from customer
"@

$res
```

Output:

```
firstname                                         
--------------------------------------------------
John
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell _ISE_ is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-h -1`, `-m 1` and `set nocount on;`
Try this:

```
$res = sqlcmd -S . -m 1 -h -1 -Q @"
    use [Database1];
    set nocount on;
    select firstname from customer;
"@
```

Comment: that's real close, if not, on the money, however, I'm getting additional meta `Sqlcmd: Successfully connected to server '.'.`

Comment: The server is local, try omitting the line `:Connect`. You might not need it.

Comment: Try this instead: `sqlcmd -S . -m 1 -h -1 -Q @"`

Comment: You can specify a remote system with `-S` like this: `sqlcmd -S SQLServer/Instance -E -m 0 -h -1 -Q "set nocount on;select getdate()"` Use `-E` if the connection is trusted, otherwise use username and password.

Comment: Never mind my `-m -1` comment (since removed); I saw a `-1` that wasn't there; it is there with `-h`, but - unlike with `-m` - the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=odbc%2Cwindows&pivots=cs1-bash#-h-headers) don't mention the need to directly attach the `-1` to the option name.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell is about automation using types. `sqlcmd.exe` goes back to parsing text strings. `sqlcmd.exe` doesn't know types from Shinola.

Use `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. It will even give back the value as the correct type, not just always string.

```
(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance DEVDW02 -Query "SELECT firstname FROM customer;").firstname

((Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance DEVDW02 -Query "SELECT firstname FROM customer;").firstname).GetType()
```